# Regex to include curly brackets in some strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a spreadsheet that contains a "find" column and a "replace" column. Note that some strings are a subset of other strings.

```
Find                    Replace
{Example1}              {50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1}
{Example1\Alarm}        {50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\Alarm}
{Example1\AlarmHigh}    {50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\AlarmHigh}
{Example1\AlarmLow}     {50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\AlarmLow}
Example2                50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2
Example2foo             50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2foo
Example2foobar          50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2foobar
ATag                    Device_Shortcut\DirectReference
Another_Tag             Winder\Local:50:I.Data.0
Another\Tag             Winder\Local:12:O.Data.1
```

I need to search a directory of files for each of the search terms and replace the discovered terms with their associated replacements. The files I'm searching could also contain capitalization errors. {Example1} Could appear as {example1}, {ExAmPle1}, {exAMplE}1, or any other combination of upper and lower case characters. I'm attempting to use regular expressions as my brute force attempt at searching all of the files was far too slow.

I've managed to put together a regular expression that works with strings that do not contain curly brackets {}. However, if a string does contain a curly bracket, my search function will not find anything in the files that I'm searching.

```
pattern = re.compile(
    r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join([re.escape(term) for term in replace_dict]),
    re.IGNORECASE
)
```

How should I form my regex to include the curly brackets as part of the search term? Also, if my search terms did not contain curly brackets, could the new regex still be used, or would I have to revert back to my current pattern?

Edit: I should probably broaden this question as I haven't yet discovered all of the possible special characters that I would need to search for. Can a regex be created that can potentially contain any combination of special characters?

Comment: The code you've shown would make a lot more sense if the context of [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75773278/12975140) were given.

Comment: Also, do you need to search for word boundaries specifically?

Answer (score 0):

**The following is the solution to the current version of the question**

You were on the right track with [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) in your original attempt. I've turned the list comprehension below into a `for` loop for clarity. The find patterns are in the list `find_patterns`, replacements are in `replacements`, and sample input strings are in `sample_inputs`:

```
import re

find_patterns = [
    "{Example1}",
    "{Example1\Alarm}",
    "{Example1\AlarmHigh}",
    "{Example1\AlarmLow}",
    "Example2",
    "Example2foo",
    "Example2foobar",
    "ATag",
    "Another_Tag",
    "Another\Tag"
]
replacements = [
    "{50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1}",
    "{50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\Alarm}",
    "{50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\AlarmHigh}",
    "{50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\AlarmLow}",
    "50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2",
    "50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2foo",
    "50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2foobar",
    "Device_Shortcut\DirectReference",
    "Winder\Local:50:I.Data.0",
    "Winder\Local:12:O.Data.1"
]
sample_inputs = [
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah{Example1}more_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah{Example1\Alarm}more_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah{Example1\AlarmHigh}more_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah{Example1\AlarmLow}more_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahExample2more_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahExample2foomore_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahExample2foobarmore_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahATagmore_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahAnother_Tagmore_stuff&$^%{",
    "blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahAnother\Tagmore_stuff&$^%{"
]
new_strings = []
for find_pattern, replacement, sample_input in zip(find_patterns, replacements, sample_inputs):
    new_string = re.sub(re.escape(find_pattern), re.escape(replacement), sample_input, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    new_strings.append(new_string)
    print(f"{sample_input}\n{new_string}\n")
```

Output:

```
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah{Example1}more_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah\{50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\}more_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah{Example1\Alarm}more_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah\{50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\Alarm\}more_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah{Example1\AlarmHigh}more_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah\{50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\AlarmHigh\}more_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah{Example1\AlarmLow}more_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah\{50M00_Dewirer_South\Example1\AlarmLow\}more_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahExample2more_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2more_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahExample2foomore_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2foomore_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahExample2foobarmore_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blah50M00_Dewirer_South\Example2foobarmore_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahATagmore_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahDevice_Shortcut\DirectReferencemore_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahAnother_Tagmore_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahWinder\Local:50:I\.Data\.0more_stuff&$^%{

blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahAnother\Tagmore_stuff&$^%{
blAh(blah}{&^%$#@!blahWinder\Local:12:O\.Data\.1more_stuff&$^%{
```

Both the find pattern and the replacement need to be escaped. The input strings don't.

---

EDIT: The following was my original answer to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75793546/2).

You're overthinking this - you don't need to worry about brackets, braces, or other special characters. All you need to do is find `r"Example\d"` where `\d` is a digit and case is ignored, and replace it with `r"50M00_Dewirer_South\\\g<0>"` where `\\` is the escaped `\` character and `\g<0>` is the entire matched substring. In Python, where `strings` is a list of the "Find" strings:

```
import re

strings = ["{Example1}",
"{Example1\\Alarm}",
"{Example1\\AlarmHigh}",
"{Example1\\AlarmLow}",
"Example2",
"Example2foo",
"Example2foobar"]

pattern = re.compile(r"Example\d", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
replaced_strings = [re.sub(pattern, r"50M00_Dewirer_South\\\g<0>", item) for item in strings]
```

Output:

```
['{50M00_Dewirer_South\\Example1}', 
 '{50M00_Dewirer_South\\Example1\\Alarm}',
 '{50M00_Dewirer_South\\Example1\\AlarmHigh}',
 '{50M00_Dewirer_South\\Example1\\AlarmLow}',
 '50M00_Dewirer_South\\Example2',
 '50M00_Dewirer_South\\Example2foo',
 '50M00_Dewirer_South\\Example2foobar']
```

These are just the Python representations of the strings, when they're written to file they'll just contain a single `\`.

Comment: Its not as simple as just searching for "Example". "Example" could literally be any string that you can think of.

Comment: @kubiej21 OK, but your question only gave `Example+digit` as the string to search for. I've answered the question as posted. In general, but *especially* with regex questions, you need to be *very clear* about exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @kubiej21 okay, I've come up with a solution to your revised question, please see above. In the future, though, please don't move the goalposts halfway through the game, so to speak.

Comment: You're only searching each sample input string for *one* of the search patterns, rather than all of them. You could fix this with a nested `for` loop, but it would be more efficient to create a regular expression that can match any of the search terms. The question makes more sense with the context from the asker's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75773088/what-can-i-do-to-improve-the-performance-of-a-simple-string-search-and-replace-s) (and the answer to it).